# What are the performance implications of interopping with other languages via system calls?

Tags: node.js, interop

Suppose I'm writing a program in node.js (or perhaps another typical back-end scripting language). Suppose further I have a C function `f` (or a python function, or what have you) that does some pure data transformation.

If I want to use `f` in my node program, there are two approaches:

1. Bind `f` via something like node-gyp that makes it callable from JavaScript land.
2. Make `f` into a binary (or, in the case of a language like python, a single `f.py` interface) that sits on the file system, and then call it from node as if were any other system command (so that one can then take the output from the system call as a string, convert it into node.js data, and then use it).

**Question:** What are the performance implications of choosing (2) over (1)?

This is important because if you are using a language like C to make some aspect of your application run significantly faster, then using (2) would seem pointless if it slowed things down past some threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost of 1 is the cost of loading the native code, transfering arguments (ffi), calling the native code, and transfering arguments back. With loading being done only once.

The cost of 2 is always going to be the cost to startup the process, running the process, converting the results back from strings.

If the cost of `f` is high, you may never see a difference between 1 and 2. If the cost of `f` is low, then 2 will take longer because the process startup overhead will dominate.

However, depending on the complexity of `f` (it might be a very large data-processing application in C), it's almost always faster to create a native binding like 1. Avoiding process startup overhead is important, it also reduces the total amount of memory needed to run your application.

Alternatively you could do option:

3. Have the C code talk over a local network socket. Accepting requests and responding with answers when the computation is done.

This has the benefit of scaling out to multiple nodes if you need it.

Comment: In practice, it seems that you wouldn't outsource `f` to another language *unless* the cost of running `f` was high (in which case startup time isn't as important, and (2) becomes relatively not as bad).

Comment: Calling `f` in another language might be because you need a feature of the language not available in the current language you're using, like direct access to hardware or syscalls that aren't exposed to you in any way e.g. madvise, mmap/

Comment: Another question: is it fair to say that with a language like C or C++, where the startup time is basically 0, that the added cost of (2) is merely the cost of converting results from strings?

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarking both for your use case is the only way to be sure but method 1 is
likely to be faster.

The startup cost of calling a binary and starting an interpreter for python/perl/blah would likely kill any performance gain you might get using their  Foreign Function Interface (FFI). Startup cost is one of the reasons why Apache has mod_python, mod_perl and why FastCGI exists.

Another thing to consider is that you're adding another language to the mix and this might kill **performance of the team** ie now everyone needs to know two languages and two FFI methods etc. If your app is in Node, keep it in Node and use node to call native methods.